# Openlayers 3 - ol.layer.Image rendering on drag'n'drop

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using the lastest version of Openlayers 3, aka 3.15.1.
I want to use

```
layer = new ol.layer.Image({
    map: olMap,
    source: new ol.source.ImageVector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        style: layerStyle
    })
});
```

because i have some layer and a lots a features with hover events, so i wanted to put some layer into an ImageLayer to have better perf.

But when i drag'n'drop my ImageLayer, the part that are out of screen are not rendering when dragging, only when the drop occurs.

Is there something to get a render even when dragging (and animating, interacting, etc...)

i'm ok if i need to modify the openlayers build

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your `ol.source.ImageVector` with a higher `ratio` value, e.g. `2` instead of the default of  `1.5`. This will pre-render a larger image, so you won't reach the edge of the rendered map so early. See http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageVector.html.

Comment: i tried it, but didn't work :(
and if i put a too high value, the perf drop seriously